# Token generated outside controller is too long and it's rejected by ConfirmEmail on Controller in MVC C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am updating my question as I have made some progress. 
Thanks in advance for your support.
**Question:**
I am using GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync to create a token outside the Controller (it's working fine), but somehow my token is longer than the ones created within the Controller using the GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync and therefore the ConfirmEmail action rejects the token. (Error: Invalid Token).
I have tried Machinekey on webconfig, HttpUtility.UrlEncode, but I am still stuck.
  How to sort out the Invalid Token error on Controller ConfirmEmail?

Guys, can you help me please!
Thanks.

Here is my Code:

RegisterUser (outside Controller)

```
 public async Task RegisterUserAsync()
        {
            var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
            var UserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);

            var query = from c in db.Customer
                        where !(from o in db.Users
                                select o.customer_pk)
                            .Contains(c.customer_pk)
                        select c;
            var model = query.ToList();

            if (query != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in model)
                {
                    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = item.email, Email = item.email, customerId = item.customerId};
                    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                        MailMessage message = new MailMessage
                        {
                            IsBodyHtml = true
                        };
                        message.Subject = "Confirm Email";
                        message.To.Add(item.email1);
                        message.Body = "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>";

                        client.SendAsync(message, "userToken");

                        //Assign Role User Here
                        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Client");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

SendEmailConfirmation method (outside Controller)

```
public async Task<string> SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(string userID)
        {
            var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
            var UserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);
            var url = new UrlHelper();
            var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyApp");
            UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(
                provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
            string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userID);
            string encodedCode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);

            string callbackUrl = "http://localhost/Accounts/ConfirmEmail?userId=" + userID + "&code=" + encodedCode;
            return callbackUrl;
        }
```

where db is

```
ApplicationdDbContext db = new ApplicationdDbContext();
```

ConfirmEmail within the Identity Controller (Accounts Controller) - I've created Accounts instead of Account controller but it's working fine.

```
//
        // GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
        {
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            var confirmed = await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(userId);
            if (confirmed)
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(userId);
            }
            var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code); //Here I get the error (Token Invlaid, despite the token and userId being displayed)
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                ViewBag.userId = userId;
                ViewBag.code = code;
            }

            return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(SetPasswordViewModel model, string userId, string code)
        {
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            var result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(userId, model.NewPassword);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                }

                return RedirectToLocal(userId);
            }

            ViewBag.userId = userId;
            ViewBag.code = code;

            AddErrors(result);

            return View(model);
        }
```

I have worked for hours in this code but until now I can't sort it out.
Thanks for any comments or solution.  The reason for this approach is that I have to use task scheduler(I'm using fluentscheduler, which is working fine).

Comment: Not exactly sure what is your question. Yes, the scenario you describe is fully feasible.Only I'd be sending out a link to reset password rather than temporary passwords.

Comment: yes it is..   try to check this peace of code on https://gist.github.com/AlphaHydrae/a95b2d898b3ba7e47db1c0cbf184394b

Comment: Thanks guys for your support but I'm still stuck.  At the moment i am able to send the email but the token in invalid when reach ConfirmEmail Action on controller, my GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync generates somehow a longer token and its rejected on controller.